# Measure failed SMTP logins with Telegraf and InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb, telegraf, influxql

There is a lot of questions about the root of the problem without answers so I would like to specify my problem a little deeper to hopefully get some ideas about how can I achieve it.

**Warning:** InfluxDB newbie is here so please bear with me.

So, my root problem is you can not group by fields in InfluxQL because fields aren't indexed. However, as long as I understood I have to write down some field to get a row in InfluxDB, it cannot contain only tags.

The idea was to collect failed login attempts from Postfix logs by parsing log entries and generating measurements that could be graphed later by Chronograph.

The original log entry is like this:

```
Nov 18 06:30:55 moonshine postfix/smtps/smtpd[11656]: warning: unknown[1.2.3.4]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
```

This log entry generates the following measurement (in InfluxDB line protocol):

```
smtp_failed_login,host=moonshine,path=/var/log/mail.log,program=postfix/smtps/smtpd source_ip="1.2.3.4" 1574301125000000000
```

You can see Telegraf convers the client's IP to a field. It's just because I think I need some field here and IP was the best applicant here.

As long as I understand the documentation, Telegraf's input parser cannot make a tag and field at once, I have to decide which go to which place.

The goal I want to create multiple charts in Chronograph, based on 1) how much failed log entries generated in the selected interval and 2) make charts - and alerts - if a certain IP reaches a limit about failed logins to trigger an alert message and also take an action. It's a bit similar to Fail2Ban, but I really want to get charts too because sometimes failed login actions are valid.

I just can't figure how to query the 2) and have some basic ideas about 1). If someone could help me giving pointers about how to write these queries or how to change my schema to achieve the goal I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

Your schema doesn't looks good. `source_ip` should be `tag`, because you will want to use it for grouping + create constant `field`, e.g. `value=1`. Then:

1.) how much failed log entries generated in the selected interval:

```
SELECT COUNT(value) 
FROM <measurement>
WHERE <time condition>
```

2.) IPs, which has reached defined limit in the selected interval (subqueries are used here, it may have a better single query equivalent):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(value) 
  FROM <measurement>
  WHERE <time condition>
  GROUP BY "source_ip"
) WHERE count_value > <failed-login-limit>
```

Queries ^^ are not prepared for copy&paste testing. They may need some development, so please check InfluxDB doc for proper syntax.

Comment: How do you create a constant field with Telegraph? Or can I put just any value to it?

Comment: I don't know. Check the doc. It is not clear, which input plugin are you using and what is used plugin configuration.

Comment: I use the logparser plugin. I cannot make a single 1 from it, but I can put in e.g. a fixed string as field value.